# Speed of divergence of $\frac{1}{x^\alpha}$ for different values of $\alpha$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I am studying the different behavior of the integral
$$
\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^\alpha}dx,\ \ \alpha>0
$$
for $\alpha\geq 1$, and $\alpha<1$.

Is there a specific way to refer to the speed of divergence of the integrand in the two cases so as to relate such speed of divergence with the convergence of the integral?

I can tell that in the first case our function is a hyperbola, which might be associated with the hyperbolic speed of divergence. However, I would like to know formally the characterization of the case $\alpha <1$, can we say that its speed of divergence to infinity is polynomial? How to call such function?

Comment: as $x\rightarrow0$, does $\frac{1}{x}$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$  converges?

Comment: Sorry, I am talking about the integral and the function interchangeably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would make the most sense to look at a group of functions:
$$f_\alpha(\epsilon)=\int_\epsilon^1\frac{dx}{x^\alpha}$$
then compare the orders of $f_\alpha$, obviously the integral your interested in is as $\epsilon\to0^+$